# Общее привязанное свойство

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Код ниже выполняет привязку строк из CheckedListBox1 к свойствам Value1 и Value2, которые в свою очередь связаны с TextBox-ами. Подскажите пожалуйста, как в C# WinForms VS2010 исправить следующую проблему: нужно чтобы свойство Value2 (привязанное к TextBox2) было одинаковым для всех строк из CheckedListBox1, т.е. после привязки, если в TextBox2 вводится текст, то для всех строк из CheckedListBox1 этот текст имел последнее введенное значение? Сейчас для каждой строки из CheckedListBox1 значение для TextBox2 меняется.

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
    }

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  people = new BindingList<Person>();
  foreach (var item in CheckedListBox1.Items)
    {
       Person p = new Person
       {
                Name = item.ToString(),
                Value1 = TextBox1.Text,
                Value2 = TextBox2.Text,
       };
       people.Add(p);
    }

   var listBox = ((ListBox)CheckedListBox1);
   listBox.DataSource = people;
   listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

   TextBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
   TextBox2.DataBindings.Clear();

   TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", people, "Value1", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
   TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", people, "Value2", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

Comment: т.е. у вас одно из свойств должно быть одинаковым у всех? В текущей реализации класса Person, с помощью биндингов это сделать не получится. Нужна либо отдельная логика на событиях, либо свойство должно быть действительно общим, например на основе статического поля.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!